# Pygame Sprites "Colliding" before they Touch

Tags: python, pygame

New to coding and creating a game using python and pygame. Game is similar to Flappy bird but in space and the pipes are meteors.

Working on creating an event when the sprites collide, but the pygame.sprite.spritecollide function doesn't seem to be working properly. The function is triggered an inch or so(on the screen) before the sprites actually touch. If the player sprites falls through the meteor sprite then the event is not triggered.

```
import pygame
import random

# Initialize the game engine 
pygame.init()

# Define colors
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# Define done 
done = False

def create_meteor():
    meteor = Meteor(WHITE, width, height)
    meteor_sprites_list.add(meteor)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # This class will be the sprite controlled by player

    # -- Methods
    def __init__(self, filename, color, HW, HH):
        # Constructor function 
        # Call parent'c constructor 
        super().__init__()

        # Set height, width
        self.image = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert_alpha()
        # Set background color to transparent
        self.image.set_colorkey(color)

        # Make top-left corner the passed in locatin 
        self.rect = pygame.rect.Rect((HW, HH), self.image.get_size())

        # How much to add to current player position
        self.dy = 0 

    def ignite(self):
        self.dy = -400

    def update(self, dt, screen):

        #apply gravity
        self.dy = min(400, self.dy + 40)
        self.rect.y += self.dy * dt

        self.rect.topleft = (self.rect.x, self.rect.y)  

        # Blit image to screen
        screen.blit(self.image, (320, self.rect.y))
        pygame.display.flip()


# Define new clas for meteor
class Meteor(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color, width, height):
        # Takes in parameters for color, width (x position) , and height (y postion)

        # Call the parent class 
        super().__init__()

        # Make list of image file location
        self.meteor_list = ["meteors/meteor1.png"]

        # Randomly select meteor from above list
        self.new_meteor = random.choice(self.meteor_list)

        # Load graphic that is in file folder  
        self.image = pygame.image.load(self.new_meteor).convert_alpha()

        # Set background to transparent
        self.image.set_colorkey(color)

        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Random starting location
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(width, (width + 100))
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(0, height)

        # Random movement to the left
        self.change_x = random.randrange(-10,-5)
        self.change_y = random.randrange(-4,3)

    # ---- Attributes  
    # What meteor does each cycle through
    def update(self): 
        # Move bad block down 3 at a time 
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y


# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

background_size = pygame.image.load("background.png")
# Get dimensions of background
width = background_size.get_width()
height = background_size.get_height() 
HW, HH = width/2, height/2
size = (width, height)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)


# Load image for star background  
background = pygame.image.load("background.png").convert_alpha()
# Seperate becuase error when placed before screen

# Creates a list of sprites. Each object in program is added to list. Managed by a class called "group"
meteor_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()


# Create spaceship 
player = Player("player.png", WHITE, HW, HH)

# Create meteor sprites on the screen     
create_meteor()

#-----Main Program Loop 
while not done:
    dt = clock.tick(30)
    # Main event Loop 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            player.ignite()

#-----Game Logic 
    # Draw background
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    # Update Sprites 
    # Update meteor sprite
    meteor_sprites_list.update()
    # Update player sprite
    player.update(dt/1000. , screen)
    # Draw meteors
    meteor_sprites_list.draw(screen) 


    # Check to see if player has collided with meteor
    meteor_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, meteor_sprites_list, True, pygame.sprite.collide_circle)

    # -- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

# Make sure to quit 
pygame.quit()
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated and welcomed. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: It's not very easy to reproduce your problem because there are 20+ assets necessary. Can you offer a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Apologize for the pre edit length.

Comment: There are some parts of the code that could be improved. I suggest to post your game on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pygame to get some tips, but it's only allowed to post complete, working examples there.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I'll head over there once I get my game all done!

Comment: I think you can already post the program in its current form, you only need to fix the rect problem, so that it's bug-free. I've got only a few suggestions. One thing that should be removed immediately is the `pygame.display.flip()` call in the `update` method of the player. You should call that only once per frame, otherwise the graphics could flicker and it's also bad for the performance.

Comment: After your answer I tried to get rid of the flickering, and removing the `pygame.display.flip()` was one of the first things I did. Great to get some reassurance I did the right thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If something is wrong with the collision detection, it usually helps to draw (or print) the rects of the involved sprites. 
You're not blitting the image at the x-coordinate of the rect, so the rect will actually be further to the right.

```
screen.blit(self.image, (320, self.rect.y))  # self.rect.x is equal to `HW` not 320.
```

Just blit the image at the rect instead:

```
screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I changed the code and everything is working as it should be now.